# How to know whether a class has been initialized or not?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, instrumentation

Either with a CustomClassloader or a Java agent + Instrumentation API is quite simple and straightforward to get all classes that have been loaded by the JVM. However, the list of classes that have been **initialized** does not seem so easy to get. (I actually wonder if there is any way to get it)

So, is there any way to know whether a class has been initialized?

--
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I've a piece of software that already instruments classes and adds a particular static field to each class (which I would like to collect after executing the program). as I exactly know which classes have been loaded, I can easily retrieve that field by reflection. however, if a class X has been loaded but not initialized, the reflection will triggers the static constructor of the class, which will initialized all static variables, etc. so, if there is a way to know that a particular class X has not been initialized, I won't even try to get my static field from that class.

Comment: If you already instruments classes,  you can add static initializer to classes with code, that will collect them, like `MyClassesCollector.list.add(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());`

Also serviesability agents can do that, but they will freeze target process.

Comment: thanks for you commend @commit-man. yes, I could add a static initializer to instrumented classes. however, the instrumented classes will get a direct dependency on my runtime/agent.jar. and when custom class loader are used it isn't 100% guarantee that dependency will be accessible from the instrumented classes.

Comment: Agent will be added in system class loader, also you can modify bootstrap class path via instrumentation api or agent's manifest, it is not a problem

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about Instrumentation API but one possible way is to use JVMTI [`GetClassStatus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetClassStatus) function.

With tool interface you can obtain all classes loaded by JVM and find out those without `JVMTI_CLASS_STATUS_INITIALIZED` status flag

```cpp
JavaVM *jvm;
jvmtiEnv *jvmti;
jvmtiError err;

env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);
jvm->GetEnv((void **) &jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_1_2);

jint classCount = 0;
jclass * classes;

jvmti->GetLoadedClasses(&classCount, &classes);
for (int i = 0; i < classCount; i++) {
    jint classStatus = 0;
    jvmti->GetClassStatus(classes[i], &classStatus);

    if (classStatus != JVMTI_CLASS_STATUS_PRIMITIVE
        && classStatus != JVMTI_CLASS_STATUS_ARRAY
        && classStatus != JVMTI_CLASS_STATUS_ERROR
        && !(classStatus & JVMTI_CLASS_STATUS_INITIALIZED)) {
        // static initializer is not finished yet
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. although it seems to do exactly what I need, I would rather prefer a more Java-based solution. just because will be painful to support different OS, different Archs (32, 64), etc.

Comment: @josecampos It seems to me that this functionality is very low-level. So java-based solution will also use native library to inspect class statuses. Anyway if you'll find any solution I'll be also glad to see it :)

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/odnoklassniki/jvmti-tools#vmtrace

There is already ready-to-use agent source to track loading/preparation stages of classes